# Is this sentence correct? "My English may be not perfect."

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm from Poland and it's really important for me to get the answer quite quickly, thank you.

Comment: It is correct. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: It's perfect.​​      ​

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> My English may not be perfect.

is correct, but possibly *incomplete*. Usually there is added context

> My English may not be perfect ***(but*** *I try really hard.)*

Comment: It can serve as a standalone incomplete thought as well.

Comment: I would agree with Peter in saying that "My English may not be perfect." sounds incomplete, particularly with the use of the word "may". I would change it to "My English **is** not perfect." to make it more of a complete thought.